# CouchBase sync_gateway + web application?

Tags: android, node.js, angularjs, api, couchbase

By using couchbase sync_gateway for mobile sync(android,ios) you can still use the database from custom server side app?

My application needs to run on both mobile and web. I have angularjs for browsers and nodejs/express for server side.

If I will update the database form **browser->node->couchbase** ... mobile clients will get db update?! I think this is with no revisions so?!

Answer (score 1):

if you are using the Node.js smart client for Couchbase Server, you can still co-exist with Couchbase Lite mobile clients using a workflow we call "bucket shadowing". For more information on this, check out: https://github.com/couchbase/sync_gateway/wiki/Bucket-Shadowing

Alternatively, you could use a Node.js library that interfaces directly with the Sync Gateway instead. For example, cradle: https://github.com/flatiron/cradle

But, for most use cases, I would recommend the bucket shadowing method instead.

Comment: It seams like Shadowing is doubling + extra my required storage and I can't afford that :|. I also found https://github.com/couchbase/sync_gateway/issues/115 , wondering if I can use it. I might decide to install sync_gateway on my application server so I'll not get in trouble with CORS because my web clients will represent around 20% from all. Have anyone successfully made this? And if Yes, what are the advantages / disadvantages ? Thanks

Comment: @IceDevil Have you had anymore luck with this? I'm going through the same process right now. I've setup the Shadowing (which is pretty snappy), but there are still a couple of edge cases with sync that you can run into.

Comment: @SJoshi take a look at: [https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/1666](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/1666) I'm not using shadowing, for me is a really bad idea

Answer (score 1):

I've attempted to approach it from a similar direction in PHP.

Sync_gateway is based on CouchDB API but has some changes and missing features in it's architecture when compared to a normal Couchbase or CouchDB instance.

Sync/Admin REST API:

- Attachments aren't supported: Sync_gateway runs in memory passing JSON documents to clients and isn't designed to store larger binary files.
- Views aren't supported (except for a few special sync_gateway views): A sync_gateway pipes documents through channels to the authenticated users instance of Couchbase Lite. View design documents are passed also then ran on the client to analyse the documents they have locally. Structurally views otherwise have no ability to change their contents based on which user is authenticated, as they are pre-computed indexes.
- Get/store docs, adding/removing users, channels, roles, DB compact, registering new databases as sync_gateway and a few other handy features are exposed.

So depending on your needs it is possible to connect a web-app to sync_gateway and retrieve documents, however "bucket shadowing" with separate ACL system for the web-app is likely the solution for most applications.

Alternatively you could compile Couchbase Lite for the server node and have the web-app connect to it, however this Couchbase Lite instance will only represent a single user and contain only their channel's documents.

PHP Client for Sync Gateway: https://github.com/mryellow/PHP-on-CouchSync/

Answer (score 0):

Update: Nowadays probably the best way to go is with [PouchDB](http://pouchdb.com/) for the web side. You can monitor changes with AngularJS and make responsive interfaces that will automatically react to your data changes in the browser.